# How to choose a HTML element to be used on model binding

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

My view has many controls generated by HTML helpers, like HTMLEditFor, but I have a `<select>` that is created "manually" and not by a HTML helper.

My view sends its data to one of the overloaded actions in my controller, but I need to fill one property of the model instance with the value from the HTML element.

How can I do this?

```
<select id="CityID" 
    data-url="@Url.Action("GetCitiesByStateId", "Cities", new { Area = "Panel" })"
    data-bind="options: cities, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Selecione uma cidade', value: selectedCity">
</select>
```

`CityID` is the name of a property in my model.

Comment: Whether you use Html Helpers or manually write the Html the model binding should work the same. Can you post some code.

Comment: @Juliano Nunes Silva Oliveira did my answer help you? or are you still looking for answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the name attribute on your selectlist to send it to the controller

```
<select id="CityID" name="CityID"
    data-url="@Url.Action("GetCitiesByStateId", "Cities", new { Area = "Panel" })"
    data-bind="options: cities, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Selecione uma cidade', value: selectedCity">
</select>
```